# nodejs socket hang up error in nested callback

Tags: node.js

I try to put many callbacks in a callback, but the program will shut down after the return of several success requests and post "socket hang up" error. I try to collect data from response and output them at once, can someone tell me which part goes wrong...
By the way, I hide the details of request method, I promise the request method works on http call.

```
http.request(options1,function(data){
    var condition=data.length;
    var result=[];
    data.foreach(item,function(data){
        http.request(options2, function(data){
             if(data) result.push(data);
             condition--;
             if(condition<=0) console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

for my http.request method

```
var request=function(options,callback){
    http.request(options,function(res){
        var body;

        res.on('data',function(chunk){
             body+=chunk;
        });
        res.on('end',function(){
             callback(JSON.parse(body));
        });

    request.end();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct usage of [`http.request()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).

- The `http.request()` callback is passed an [IncomingMessage](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) object, not buffered response data.

  - **EDIT:** Your custom request() should look something like this, although you should handle errors too. Note the proper placement of `request.end()` and initializing `var body = ''`:

    ```
    function request(options, callback) {
      http.request(options,function(res) {
        var body = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data',function(chunk) {
          body += chunk;
        }).on('end',function() {
          callback(JSON.parse(body));
        });
      }).end();
    }
    ```
- You're missing `.end()` for your requests so that node.js knows you are ready to actually send the HTTP request: `http.request(..., ....).end();`. This is the cause of your particular error... the server hangs up the connection because it got tired of waiting for your request after the TCP connection was opened.

Comment: Well, this "http.request" is not the one in node, I've already wrap it in my own "http.request" method, and it works like that.The response handle I've already have it done inside the method, and I tested this method, it works, sorry for the miss leading.

Comment: Ok, but your custom request method isn't correct either. The built-in `http.request()` callback is passed an `IncomingMessage` object (just `res`), not `(req, res, error)`.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Make sure in your main code with the loops that you're actually using your own custom `request()` instead of `http.request()` that you're still showing...

Comment: I've found the problem, it is irrelevant to this function, but still thanks for the help.